# How do you Select TOP x but still get a COUNT of the whole query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a webpage to interactively filter results based on filter criteria as it is specified by the user.  I only want to return from SQL the TOP 20 rows but I want to know how many rows met the criteria (Count).  I want to be able to tell the user: "here are the top 20 rows matching your criteria, and BTW, there were 2,000 additional rows I'm not showing here".

I know I could simply run the query twice but EWWWW that's expensive and wasteful.  How can I achieve what I want without over taxing the database?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(*) OVER()`

```
SELECT TOP 20 *, 
       COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalMatchingRows
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type='P'
ORDER BY number
```

Doing two queries may work out more efficient however especially if you have narrower indexes that can be used in determining the matching row count but don't cover the entire `SELECT` list.

Comment: I am an idiot, you are a zen master.  :-)  I love SQL experts, no frills, just facts.  Thank you Martin.

Answer (score 0):

select COUNT(*) from Process_Master where dt_time=(select top 1 (dt_time) from Process_Master order by DT_TIME desc)