# TSQL - TOP and COUNT in one SELECT

Tags: sql, t-sql

i try to combine these two statements to one, but all my tries failed!
Is it possible to merge them?

```
-- Is there a open answer?
SELECT CASE COUNT(tbl_Communication.pk_Communication) WHEN 0 
       THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS hasAnsweredCom
FROM   tbl_Communication 
JOIN   tbl_CommunicationElements ON tbl_CommunicationElements.pk_Communication = tbl_Communication.pk_Communication
WHERE  tbl_Communication.pk_Ticket = @pk_Ticket
  AND tbl_Communication.isClosed = 0 
  AND tbl_Communication.pk_CommunicationType = (SELECT pk_CommunicationType
                                                FROM   tbl_CommunicationType
                                                WHERE  name = 'query')

-- Get the answer text
SELECT TOP 1 tbl_Communication.subject AS hasAnsweredComStepName
FROM   tbl_Communication 
JOIN   tbl_CommunicationElements ON tbl_CommunicationElements.pk_Communication = tbl_Communication.pk_Communication
WHERE  tbl_Communication.pk_Ticket = @pk_Ticket 
  AND tbl_Communication.isClosed = 0 
  AND tbl_Communication.pk_CommunicationType = (SELECT pk_CommunicationType
                                                FROM   tbl_CommunicationType
                                                WHERE  name = 'query')
ORDER BY tbl_Communication.pk_Communication
```

Comment: `TOP 1` ordered by what? Also look at `CASE WHEN EXISTS` rather than counting them all and setting a flag if non zero.

Comment: why order? both statements will result in 1 single row/field.

Comment: @Eichenwald: Yes, but the second needs a `TOP 1` which suggests that there are multiple rows, so you should order them, otherwise the output is unpredictable. Even if it doesn't matter for you (now) it's a bad habit to omit the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: ahh, ok i'll edit the question :)

Comment: @Martin Smith: When i'm right then `CASE WHEN EXISTS` would end up in a `SELECT` with a `SUBSELECT` within the `EXISTS`. Like in this [example](http://peoplesoft.wikidot.com/case-when-exists-sql). I try to save some time by using less `selects`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you Select TOP x but still get a COUNT of the whole query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662800/how-do-you-select-top-x-but-still-get-a-count-of-the-whole-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right join trick.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    CASE WHEN tbl_CommunicationElements.pk_Communication IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END hasAnsweredCom
    , tbl_Communication.subject AS hasAnsweredComStepName
FROM   tbl_Communication 
JOIN   tbl_CommunicationElements ON tbl_CommunicationElements.pk_Communication = tbl_Communication.pk_Communication
RIGHT JOIN (VALUES(1)) AS Ext(x) ON (
  tbl_Communication.pk_Ticket = @pk_Ticket 
  AND tbl_Communication.isClosed = 0 
  AND tbl_Communication.pk_CommunicationType = (SELECT pk_CommunicationType
                                                FROM   tbl_CommunicationType
                                                WHERE  name = 'query')
)
```

Comment: thx, but this won't work because the `tbl_CommunicationElements.pk_Communication` can't be NULL and it should be `tbl_Communication`.

Comment: this is an outer join, so tbl_CommunicationElements.pk_Communication will be null when hasAnsweredCom = 0

Comment: wow, i don't understand what happans here but it works ;) thx alot!

Comment: This helped, all I was looking for was Any-C#-style e.g.
SELECT  p.[Id]
  , CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP(1) id FROM KidsTable WHERE pId = p.[Id] AND OtherProperty IN ('A','B','C')) IS NULL 
    THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
   AS HasAbcChild
FROM ParentsTable p

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to put the two results on one line, the following works:

```
select (CASE count(*) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS hasAnsweredCom,
       MAX(case when seqnum = 1 then subject end) as hasAnsweredComStepName
from (SELECT tbl_Communication.pk_Communication, tbl_Communication.subject,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (order by pk_communication) as seqnum                               
      FROM   tbl_Communication 
      JOIN   tbl_CommunicationElements ON tbl_CommunicationElements.pk_Communication = tbl_Communication.pk_Communication
      WHERE  tbl_Communication.pk_Ticket = @pk_Ticket
        AND tbl_Communication.isClosed = 0 
        AND tbl_Communication.pk_CommunicationType = (SELECT pk_CommunicationType
                                                      FROM   tbl_CommunicationType
                                                      WHERE  name = 'query')
     ) t
```

The second value will be NULL if there are no answers.

As for returning two rows.  My guess is that `subject` is a string whereas `hasAnsweredCom` is an integer.  The types conflict, so any sort of `union` or bringing the results together will probably result in a type conflict on the second row.